# How to split a string into an array based on length

Tags: c#, vcf-vcard

I wanted to split a string of length 200 characters and place them in the request DTO data member noteline1---noteline18. I want to make sure that only 78 characters are allowed and the remaining characters should be moved to another data member(if noteline1 is filled with 78 characters, then it should fill the remaining characters to another empty noteline). I have used the following code

```
if (requestNoteReason.Length < 78)
 {
     if (reqPropertyInfo.Name.ToLower() == null)
      {
            reqPropertyInfo.SetValue(request, requestNoteReason, null);
           break;
      }
 }

      else
      {
          reqPropertyInfo.SetValue(request, requestNoteReason.Substring(0, 78), null);
          requestNoteReason = requestNoteReason.Substring(78, requestNoteReason.Length - 78);
          i++;

         continue;
     }
```

The above code work fine but I want that it should not place the remaining string character on the non-empty noteline data member. It should first find the remaining empty Noteline(noteline1---noteline18) and then assign the remaining characters on them. How will I achieve it?

Comment: I can't parse "I want that it should not place the remaining string character on the variable which already have value in it" - could you clarify? It's not clear which variables you have available... is there any reason you're not just using a `List<string>`?

Comment: I have edited the code now. I think it will clear up things

Comment: @HimanshuNegi Do you use this code `if (reqPropertyInfo.Name.ToLower() == null)
` to check if a property has a value?
And is this property represents a noteline(s) you're talking about?

Comment: It's not clearer... maybe expanding the code so we can see the loop that this is in?